# The shortest way to print all lines in the file using python

Tags: python, file, printing

I try to print the whole file in the shortest possible way.
So far I have managed to do this in three lines of code.

```
        with open(file) as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                print(line, end="")
```

Can anyone do it shorter, in two lines?

Comment: Is there a reason you're trying to do this in fewer lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
with open(fname) as f:
    print(f.readlines(),end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Get ready:

```
for line in open(file).readlines():
     print(line, end="")
```

This opens the file, and reads all the lines in the same line of code.

Comment: Not closing files is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Since closing the file is not required. This. However it is bad not to close the file.

```
with open('file') as f:
    print(f.readlines())
```

Answer (score 0):

Technically you can do it in one line, but it's not recommended to open files without a `with` statement:

```
list(map(print, open(file)))
```